# How to prevent timeout(...) from cancelling the stream emission?

Tags: rx-java2

Here is what I want to do....

Perform a bunch of tasks. Each task needs to complete in x number of seconds.
If it does not complete, log a timeout and continue with handling the next emission.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<String> source = Observable.create(emitter -> {
        emitter.onNext(task(0, "A"));
        emitter.onNext(task(2, "B")); // this one times out
        emitter.onNext(task(0, "C"));
        emitter.onNext(task(0, "D"));
        emitter.onComplete();
        });

    source.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
          .timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Observable.just("timeout"))
          .blockingSubscribe(s -> System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + s));
}

private static String task(int i, String string) {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(i);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }

    return string;

}
```

Actual result

> RECEIVED: A
>   RECEIVED: timeout

Expected result

> RECEIVED: A
>   RECEIVED: timeout
>   RECEIVED: C
>   RECEIVED: D

Basically I don't want the emissions to terminate on a timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could defer the execution of the tasks and apply `timeout` with each separately:

```
Observable<String> source = Observable.create(
        (ObservableEmitter<Callable<String>> emitter) -> {
    emitter.onNext(() -> task(0, "A"));
    emitter.onNext(() -> task(2, "B")); // this one times out
    emitter.onNext(() -> task(0, "C"));
    emitter.onNext(() -> task(0, "D"));
    emitter.onComplete();
})
.concatMap(call ->
    Observable.fromCallable(call)
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
       .timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Observable.just("timeout")) 
);

source
      .blockingSubscribe(s -> System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + s));
```

Comment: The emitter is of type `ObservableEmitter<String>`  but you have it as `ObservableEmitter<Callable<String>>` which shows me a compiler error. If I get what you are saying, instead of calling the task in the observable you want me to return/emit a callable there and then execute the callable in the subscriber, is my understanding  correct?

Comment: Compiles fine for me as is; please copy and try the provided code as is. Don't execute the task in the subscriber because the thread will be wrong.

Comment: Apologies, my bad. As for the behavior as I understand it, now that the task is executed in the concatMap and handles each  observable callable tasks one by one so on timeout, it cancels but there is only one element so it proceeds to the next emitted call. Kind of feels like a flatmap behavior. Thank you for your assistance. @akarnokd.